# fluentd missing region error

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd

i want to fetch cloudwatch logs. I installed cloudwatch input plugin and configured the config file of td-agent. but im getting the error as 
"unexpected error error_class=aws::errors::MissingRegionError".

Any help on how to resolve this would be great.